# Bound on derivatives of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem:Let $f$ be analytic and bounded by $M$ in $|z| \leq r$.Prove that

$$|f^{(n)}(z)|\leq \frac{n!M}{(r-|z|)^n}$$ $(|z|<r)$

There is a hint in the book that says use the ML inequality and Cauchy's integral theorem with the contour $|\zeta-z|=r-|z|$

Given this hint it is easy for me to see that

if
$$ f^{n}(z)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\zeta-z|=r-|z|} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta$$

$$|f^{n}(z)|=|\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\zeta-z|=r-|z|} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta|$$
$$\leq |\frac{n!}{2 \pi i}| \int_{|\zeta-z|=r-|z|} \frac{|f(\zeta)|}{|(\zeta-z)^{n+1}|}|d\zeta|$$
$$\leq \frac{n!}{2 \pi } \frac{M2 \pi(r-|z|)}{(r-|z|)^{n+1}}$$
$$=\frac{n!M}{(r-|z|)^n}$$

I am having trouble understanding why the contour $|\zeta -z|=r-|z|$ was used in this proof, and how the contour was found?I read a solution that said this particular contour was chosen because the circle $|\zeta -z|=r-|z|$ lies inside the disk $|\zeta| \leq 1$, but I cannot understand why that means we should use this contour.Also how did they know $|\zeta -z|=r-|z|$ lies inside the disk $|\zeta| \leq r$?  I am really struggling to understand this.

Comment: Do you get a different result if you use $|\zeta - z| = R$ where $0 < R < r - |z|$?

Comment: @EricTowers The answer would be no, right since $f(z)$ is bounded by $M$ in the whole disk, correct?

Comment: Yes.  So is $r-|z|$ a special radius, or is it just the largest radius that still allows us to use the bound, $M$?

Comment: @EricTowers It would be the largest radius allowing the use of the bound $M$ right?So in this problem we can use any radius smaller than $r-|z|$?

Comment: I agree.  The *real* constraint is "the circle for our Cauchy integral" has to be inside the region where we have a bound on $f$.  The hint in the book uses the largest radius that meets that constraint because it is easy to write down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only know that $f$ is bounded by $M$ in the disk $D=\{|z|\leq r\}$. There is no available information about $f$ outside $D$. In the Cauchy integral theorem, you integrate over a circle centred at $z$. What would be the largest such circle contained in $D$? It would be the circle centred at $z$ that touches the boundary of $D$. So its radius is the radius of $D$ minus the distance between the origin and $z$.

Comment: Can I ask you why you are using $D=\{|z| \leq r\}$ instead of $D=\{|\zeta| \leq r\}$

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: I am confused with the notation though. $|z| \leq r$ and in the problem the point $z$ that we use as the radius for the circle inside the disk  to integrate over are two different things correct ?

Comment: Yes they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Take the term $\zeta-z$ with $\zeta \in C_r$, the circle of radius $r$, and $z$ inside the circle. Then
$$
|\zeta-z|\geq \Big||\zeta|-|z| \Big| \implies|\zeta-z|^{n+1}\geq \Big||\zeta|-|z| \Big|^{n+1} \implies \frac{1}{|\zeta-z|^{n+1}} \leq \frac{1}{\Big||\zeta|-|z| \Big|^{n+1}}.
$$
Since $\zeta \in C_r$, how can this simplify? Also, in your proof, please put absolute value around $d\zeta$, since otherwise, comparing magnitudes of a complex integral don't make sense.

Comment: You just mean since $|\zeta| \leq r$ the $\zeta$ in the denominator will become $r$ right?

Comment: You are right that $|\zeta|$ will change to $r$ in the equality. But your reasoning is incorrect (more can be said than $|\zeta|\leq r$). On a picture of your integration region, where is $\zeta$?

Comment: zeta is on the perimeter of the circle $|\zeta-z|=r-|z|$ correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what your notation is. Just make it simple, $C_r$ is a circle centered at $0$ with radius $r$, oriented counterclockwise; this is actually standard notation for using Cauchy's integral formula. The part you are confused about follows from the triangle inequality, not some weird way of describing the curve.

Comment: I just realized what the hint is. I guess I solved it without the hint. To me, my method was easier, but you'll have to decide for yourself.